# SQL Somando todos os valores, como quebrar por blocos

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela que armazena valores financeiros por mês, preciso exibir por ano, fiz um `SUM` e deu certo quando tenho registro de um projeto apenas, quando tenho mais de um projeto ele soma todos os valores de todos os anos e replica em todos os projetos:

A consulta está abaixo, O banco é Oracle

```
SELECT proj.request_id Num_projeto,
       proj.project_name Nome_Projeto,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER23 Run_Rate_Aumenta_rec,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER25 R$,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER26 Porc,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER28 Run_Rate_Red_custo,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER30 R$,
       RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER31 Porc,
       (SELECT 'R$' || SUM(bp.planned_value_bse) Valor_Benefício
          FROM KCRT_REQUEST_DETAILS RD
         INNER JOIN KCRT_FG_PFM_PROJECT PROJ
            on proj.request_id = rd.request_id
         INNER JOIN PFM_LIFECYCLE_PARENT_ENTITY LC
            on lc.project_req_id = proj.request_id
         INNER JOIN FM_FINANCIAL_SUMMARY FS
            on fs.parent_id = lc.lifecycle_id
         INNER JOIN FM_BENEFIT_PERIOD_SUM BP
            on fs.benefit_id = bp.benefit_id
         INNER JOIN PPM_FISCAL_PERIODS_NLS FP
            on fp.fiscal_period_id = bp.period_id
        --WHERE proj.request_id = '31539'
         WHERE RD.BATCH_NUMBER = 1
           AND fp.fiscal_period_id in ('35967',
                                       '35974',
                                       '35962',
                                       '35956',
                                       '35980',
                                       '35997',
                                       '35985',
                                       '36002',
                                       '35945',
                                       '35992',
                                       '35940',
                                       '35950')) as BDEZESETE,
       (SELECT 'R$' || SUM(bp.planned_value_bse) Valor_Benefício
          FROM KCRT_REQUEST_DETAILS RD
         INNER JOIN KCRT_FG_PFM_PROJECT PROJ
            on proj.request_id = rd.request_id
         INNER JOIN PFM_LIFECYCLE_PARENT_ENTITY LC
            on lc.project_req_id = proj.request_id
         INNER JOIN FM_FINANCIAL_SUMMARY FS
            on fs.parent_id = lc.lifecycle_id
         INNER JOIN FM_BENEFIT_PERIOD_SUM BP
            on fs.benefit_id = bp.benefit_id
         INNER JOIN PPM_FISCAL_PERIODS_NLS FP
            on fp.fiscal_period_id = bp.period_id
        --WHERE proj.request_id = '31539'
         WHERE RD.BATCH_NUMBER = 1
           AND fp.fiscal_period_id in ('36073',
                                       '36068',
                                       '36038',
                                       '36021',
                                       '36046',
                                       '36016',
                                       '36051',
                                       '36033',
                                       '36011',
                                       '36056',
                                       '36028',
                                       '36063')) as BDEZOITO
  FROM KCRT_REQUEST_DETAILS RD
 INNER JOIN KCRT_FG_PFM_PROJECT PROJ
    on proj.request_id = rd.request_id
 INNER JOIN PFM_LIFECYCLE_PARENT_ENTITY LC
    on lc.project_req_id = proj.request_id
 INNER JOIN FM_FINANCIAL_SUMMARY FS
    on fs.parent_id = lc.lifecycle_id
 INNER JOIN FM_BENEFIT_PERIOD_SUM BP
    on fs.benefit_id = bp.benefit_id
 INNER JOIN PPM_FISCAL_PERIODS_NLS FP
    on fp.fiscal_period_id = bp.period_id
 WHERE proj.request_id = '31539'
   AND RD.BATCH_NUMBER = 1
 Group by proj.request_id,
          proj.project_name,
          proj.project_name,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER23,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER25,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER26,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER28,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER30,
          RD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER31
```

Comment: O "ano" é um period_id ? Indente melhor a sql uma sql deste tamanho sem indentação e sem conhecer a base é difícil , me parece todavia que faltou linkar o project_id nas subqueries do que creio seja o total por ano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido inserindo um join que "amarre" o request id para que some linha por linha.

Também precisei substituir o Inner Join por um left join.

Obrigado pela ajuda!